# Can bag of words be used for classifying multiple objects in a single image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image with let's say 3 objects in them: a car, a cycle and a dog. Can bag of words be implemented in such a way that it segregates and detects all three of them in the same image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bag of visual word is just a method to re-represent features. These new representations can be combined by using one of the pooling techniques. 
Now if you have multiple objects in the image this should be encoded in the new representation of the image " the output of the pooling". detecting these objects is the work of multi-label classifier.

Note that: sparse coding has been proved to be better than BoW. With sparse coding, you can use sparse based classifier to detect the occurrence of multiple objects. The sparse based classifier analyzes the sparsity of different sections of the sparse representation to find out the objects in the image

Comment: Using BoW, what should be the above mentioned representation of the image, as BoW creates a histogram taking the whole image rather than the individual objects. And also what are the pooling techniques you are referring to?

Comment: pooling techniques can be max, average ..etc pooling. The new representations are the codes that result from either using BoW or sparse coding.